# Grammar question in SAT with the usage of which

Tags: grammar

[image]

This is an SAT question. I was unable to choose between answers C and D, so I wonder what is wrong with answer C?

Why can't "which" be used, though it also creates a dependent clause?

Comment: Should be transferred to [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Disagree about the transfer. This is a usage question on verb tense agreement, not someone asking us to help them translate a concept or explain a word to them.

Comment: After consideration, I do have to agree. This question is quite a bit more complex than meets the eye, and will surely provide some excellent discussion. The original comment will stay for the sake of continuity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"They wanted X which were placed high" is a tense problem, not a "which" problem. It swaps from "future in the past" (They wanted X) to past "which were placed".

Correct options would be "They wanted X placed high", "They wanted X to be placed high", "They wanted X, which were to be placed high", or "They wanted X, which would be placed high".

Edit: Similarly, A) is wrong because "placing" is present tense and doesn't match "they wanted", which is past tense, and requires the "to place" tense to either be past or "future in the past".

Comment: Oh I see, so if they wanted something, it cannot be identified to be there already, which is what "which" seems to be implying?

Comment: Also, looking back on the question, though A) seems to be in the wrong tense, I cannot exactly explain why it is wrong, is it possible that you explain that? Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm  not convinced that there isn't a case for (c) too: 'They wanted a series of statues, which [in those days] were placed high on buttresses so the art could be admired from afar.

Comment: I think your example would work, but the [in those days] (or equivalent) would not be optional. It changes the nature of the clause.

Comment: I don't mean writing it, but interpreting the sentence in that way. e.g. They wanted a series of  XYZ computers, which were produced in Germany and the US.

Comment: If the statues had already been placed high on the buttresses by the time of the wish, why would it have been necessary for them to adorn the cathedral's exterior? They would have already adorned it.